# Excel VBA: how to set variable equal to filter criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, filter, criteria

I am trying to set a variable to x to equal the criteria that has been set by the filter in a table.
x = ?

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
 Field:=1, _
 Criteria1:=Array("1", "3", "Seattle", "Redmond"), _
 Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

how would i get:
x = 1, 3, Seattle, Redmond
or
x = Criteria1
???

Comment: You could define x as your array variable first, and then use that variable as the criteria. Or do you want to read an unknown criteria from the Table?

Answer (score 0):

With the example below, you should be able to set a Filter object and loop through it like you would an ordinary array, in order to retrieve the values.
The below example joins them in the sCrit variable, but of course you can change that to whatever you require.

Just set the lCol variable to the column number of the filtered range
and you should be good to go.

```
 Dim filt As Filter   'filters object
 Dim lCol As Long     'column in autofilter range on which the filter is applied
 Dim i As Long
 Dim sCrit As String

 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     If .AutoFilterMode Then                    ''if Autofilter is enabled
         If .AutoFilter.Filters(lCol).On Then   ''if a filter is active

             Set filt = sh.AutoFilter.Filters(lCol) 

             For i = LBound(filt.Criteria1) To UBound(filt.Criteria1)
                 sCrit = sCrit & filt.Criteria1(i) & ", "
             Next i

         End if
     End if
 End With
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Im just having trouble setting  the lCol variable to the column number of the filtered range. how could I set it If I'm using Table1 in Sheet1 and the table is in Column B, the Header is in B2 and the data is in B3:B6? thank you for the help

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it counts from the first column of the table/range; So if the filtered range starts from column B , then lCol = 1. BTW, if you are using an actual table (instead of a range with an autofilter applied to it), then .AutofilterMode should be changed to .FilterMode for it to work.